# Copy an Amazon s3 object to another folder in another bucket.

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I want to copy all the data from on bucket to another directory in another bucket on amazon s3 with java.

Like I have a bucket name **sourceBucket** and a **destBucket** and there is another directory in **destBucket**. i want to copy all the data from sourceBucket to that directory.
And i am using java. I am unable to find the solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try :

```
ObjectListing objectListing = s3.listObjects(new ListObjectsRequest()
                                .withBucketName(bucketName)
                                .withPrefix(""));

for (S3ObjectSummary objectSummary : objectListing.getObjectSummaries()) {s3client.copyObject(sourceBucketName, objectSummary.getKey(), 
                    destinationBucketName, objectSummary.getKey());}
```

Comment: There is nothing about directory in your answer. Directory path is a part of a key structure. This is not trivial and this was a part of the question.

Comment: @Basil The key = the directory in S3.  Another way to think about it is there are not directories in S3, just buckets and keys.

Comment: This answer does not take into account that `getObjectSummaries` is paged.

Answer (score 4):

s3 doesn't have folders. The "structure" you see is a key. So just copy your objects with proper keys.
From [Programmer Guide: Code Samples](http://jets3t.s3.amazonaws.com/toolkit/code-samples.html):

```
S3Object[] filteredObjects = s3Service.listObjects("sourceBucket", "appData/", null);
for(S3Object object: filteredObjects ){
    s3Service.copyObject("sourceBucket", "newAppData/" + object.getKey().substring(object.getKey().indexOf("/"), "destBucket", object, false);
}
```

Comment: sourceBucket/appData/issues/abc.zip  , destBucket/newAppData/ i want to copy appdata from sourceBucket in newAppData in destBucket.

Comment: So you need to copy all objects, that key starts with "/appData/" to the destBucket and create proper keys for them.

Comment: i have tried to get list of objects but this is showing the error that The method listObjects(String, String) in the type AmazonS3 is not applicable for the arguments (String, String, null).

Comment: Check the version of the jetS3t library. The code snippet above is copied from the current JetS3t amazon pages (http://jets3t.s3.amazonaws.com/toolkit/code-samples.html#listing)